# $\mathbb{RP}^2$ does not embed into $\mathbb{R}^3$: reduction to the differentiable case

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

It is not difficult to see that the real projective plane cannot be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$ *as a differentiable submanifold* (for example one can easily show that the complement would consist of two connected components, so the projective plane would be orientable, which is not the case). 
However, it is also well-known that there is no *continuous* embedding. My question: 
**Is there a way to reduce the continuous case to the differentiable one, thus avoiding the use of homology or other advanced tools?**

Comment: Offhand, it seems you can't hope for such an approach. For example, the Alexander horned sphere is a topological embedding $S^2\hookrightarrow S^3$, say, but any smooth approximation of it will separate $S^3$ into two disks.

Comment: I am not sure why would you try to prove this without using a general Poincare duality argument. Even the 'easy' proof in the smooth case is PD in disguise.